# Dynamically bind a textblock in a looping selector in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing an application where I have a class called UIManager in which there is a method which has an array of data

```
public void DisplayCatalog(string[] displayName, BitmapImage[] icons)
    {
        DisplayItem.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < displayName.Length; i++)
        {
             DisplayItem.Add(new ItemList { WidgetName = displayName[i], Icon = icons[i] });
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged("UI");
    }
```

Now **I want this data ie;WidgetName to be displayed in my MainPage where I have used a Looping selector.**

```
*<custom:LoopingSelector x:Name="selectorLeft" ItemMargin="5"  ItemSize="145,145" Margin="6,0,-6,22">
            <custom:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding WidgetName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </custom:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </custom:LoopingSelector>
```

*
Also **I need to scroll the looping selector Horizontally.**
How can I achieve this...??? Any valuable solutions Please.......
I have used Horizontal Looping Selector but I am not getting how to bind the data from my UIManager class on to the Horizontal Looping Selector..

```
    <toolkit:HorizontalLoopingSelector Grid.Row="0" Margin="12" Height="128"        ItemSize="128,128" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ?????}">
            <toolkit:HorizontalLoopingSelector.DataSource>
                ????????
                </toolkit:HorizontalLoopingSelector.DataSource>
             </toolkit:HorizontalLoopingSelector>
```

Comment: any answers please......

Answer (score 0):

u need to create a datasource class and bind the values to the looping selector source .its similar to binding source to the vertical looping selector.
Visit http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1-Visual-structure-and-API

Answer (score 0):

Check out this resource if you still require a horizontal loop selector:

http://blog.supaywasi.com/2011/06/horizontal-looping-selector/